# MySQL Merge String Row Values into single Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a group by which overraides null values with other values, like this:

From this

```
ID | Number |   Stringa   |   Stringb   |
1  |   1    |   String 1  |     NULL    |
2  |   1    |     NULL    |   String 2  |
```

To this

```
ID | Number |   Stringa   |   Stringb   |
1  |   1    |   String 1  |   String 2  |
```

Looking for the answer i've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325121/mysql-merge-row-values-into-single-row), but it doesn't resolve my problem

¿Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `max()`:

```
select min(id) as id, number, max(stringa) as stringa, max(stringb) as stringb
from table t
group by number;
```

Comment: I'm using strings, not dates

Comment: @IsmaelEsteruelasRegalado . . . So what?  `max()` works on all the standard base types.

Comment: Wow thanks, i didn't know a could use max for non-numerical values. Problem solved